# How many orders can I make with goecoding api free version?

Tags: reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api, google-maps-premium-plan

How many orders can I make with goecoding api free version?

This is for college research purposes.

$geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$latlng.'&key=MY_API_KEY');
            $output= json_decode($geocode);

"You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. If you did not set a custom daily request quota, verify your project has an active billing account: http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is not really a question about programming. Google maps have a limit and if you cant find it in the documentation, such as following the link you got in the error, then the best bet is probably asking some customer support.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have set up a [billing account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account#create_a_new_billing_account) with a valid payment method and [link it to your project](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#enable_billing_for_an_existing_project), you will be entitled to the recurring **$200 monthly free credits**. This means that you will only be charged once you fully consumed your free $200 monthly credits.

Take for example for Geocoding API, **free tier usage** is equivalent to free **40,000 requests per month** (varies per SKU). If you exceed the free limit, the succeeding requests will be charged accordingly of $5 per additional 1,000 Geocoding API calls. If you use other APIs, the free $200 credit will be shared among the APIs used.

As for the error you get "You have exceeded your daily request quota", this is because you haven't setup a billing account for your project yet. Note that linking your project to a valid billing account is required in order to use the Maps APIs.

Kindly file a support case via https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support in order to open a personalized communication channel if you need further assistance.

Hope this helps!